# Tensorflow error - the argument cell is not an rnn cell, property is missing, method is required, is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

Im trying to train a text summarization model and I'm getting this error:

> The argument cell is not an RNN cell: 'output_size' property is
>   missing, 'state_size' property is missing, either 'zero_state' or
>   'get_initial_state' method is required, is not callable.

I'm not sure what is the source of the problem here. My tensorflow version is 1.12.

Relevant portion of the code below:

```
class BiGRUModel(object):

def __init__(self,
             source_vocab_size,
             target_vocab_size,
             buckets,
             state_size,
             num_layers,
             embedding_size,
             max_gradient,
             batch_size,
             learning_rate,
             forward_only=False,
             dtype=tf.float32):

    self.source_vocab_size = source_vocab_size
    self.target_vocab_size = target_vocab_size
    self.buckets = buckets
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.learning_rate = learning_rate
    self.global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False, name="global_step")
    self.state_size = state_size

    self.encoder_inputs = tf.placeholder(
        tf.int32, shape=[self.batch_size, None])
    self.decoder_inputs = tf.placeholder(
        tf.int32, shape=[self.batch_size, None])
    self.decoder_targets = tf.placeholder(
        tf.int32, shape=[self.batch_size, None])
    self.encoder_len = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[self.batch_size])
    self.decoder_len = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[self.batch_size])
    self.beam_tok = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[self.batch_size])
    self.prev_att = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[self.batch_size, state_size * 2])

    encoder_fw_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(state_size)
    encoder_bw_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(state_size)
    decoder_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(state_size)

    if not forward_only:
        encoder_fw_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(
            encoder_fw_cell, output_keep_prob=0.50)
        encoder_bw_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(
            encoder_bw_cell, output_keep_prob=0.50)
        decoder_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(
            decoder_cell, output_keep_prob=0.50)


    with tf.variable_scope("seq2seq", dtype=dtype):
        with tf.variable_scope("encoder"):

            encoder_emb = tf.get_variable(
                "embedding", [source_vocab_size, embedding_size],
                initializer=emb_init)

            encoder_inputs_emb = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(
                encoder_emb, self.encoder_inputs)

            encoder_outputs, encoder_states = \
                tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(
                    encoder_fw_cell, encoder_bw_cell, encoder_inputs_emb,
                    sequence_length=self.encoder_len, dtype=dtype)

        with tf.variable_scope("init_state"):
            init_state = fc_layer(tf.concat(encoder_states, 1), state_size)
            # the shape of bidirectional_dynamic_rnn is weird
            # None for batch_size
            self.init_state = init_state
            self.init_state.set_shape([self.batch_size, state_size])
            self.att_states = tf.concat(encoder_outputs, 2)
            self.att_states.set_shape([self.batch_size, None, state_size*2])

        with tf.variable_scope("attention"):
            attention = tf.contrib.seq2seq.BahdanauAttention(
                state_size, self.att_states, self.encoder_len)
            decoder_cell = tf.contrib.seq2seq.AttentionWrapper(
                decoder_cell, attention, state_size * 2)
            wrapper_state = tf.contrib.seq2seq.AttentionWrapper(decoder_cell, attention, initial_cell_state=self.init_state)
            # wrapper_state = tf.contrib.seq2seq.AttentionWrapper(
            #     state_size=self.init_state, output_size=self.prev_att)
            decoder_initial_state = attention.zero_state(dtype, batch_size=self.batch_size * beam_width)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the last line of the code:

```
wrapper_state = tf.contrib.seq2seq.AttentionWrapper(self.init_state, self.prev_att)
```

You passed `init_state` and `prev_att` to [`AttionWrapper`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/seq2seq/AttentionWrapper) class while AttentionWrapper expected following args:

```
__init__(
    cell,
    attention_mechanism,
    attention_layer_size=None,
    alignment_history=False,
    cell_input_fn=None,
    output_attention=True,
    initial_cell_state=None,
    name=None,
    attention_layer=None
)
```

Comment: I have made changes to the script following Tensorflow documentation (see most recent edits in the relevant portion of the code). However now I get an error that 'BahdanauAttention' object has no attribute 'zero_state.

Comment: @Matthew In the last line you should use ```AttentionWrapperState``` instead of ```AttentionWrapper```. See here for more details: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/contrib.seq2seq

Comment: ahh I think I will have to downgrade tensorflow :( getting this error now: missing 4 required positional arguments: 'time', 'alignments', 'alignment_history', and 'attention_state'.

Answer (score 0):

After some time looking at this I decided to downgrade to Tf 1.11 and looks like that fixed everything.